# Compare values of two key-value objects

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, foreach, key-value

I have two objects (LABELS1 and LABELS2) that I want to loop through, and if any of the IDs from LABELS1 matches any of the IDs from LABEL2, then I want to reassign simple_value of LABELS1 with the simple_value from LABELS2. Whenever I compare the values, though, nothing ever matches. This is what I've tried below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    const LABELS1 = [
{"id":"bread", "simple_value":"Bread"},
{"id":"apple", "simple_value":"Apple"}
];
    const LABELS2 = [
{"id":"bread", "simple_value":"Bread with Butter", "detailed_value":"Toasted Bread with a Dab of Butter"},
{"id":"wine", "simple_value":"Wine", "detailed_value":"Wine with Cheese"}
];
    var labels1= [];
    var labels2= [];
        
    $.when(
    $.getJSON(LABELS1, json => {
       labels1= json;
    }), 
    $.getJSON(LABELS2, json => {       
      labels2= json; 
    })
    ).then(() => {
      Object.keys(labels1).forEach(key => {
         if (labels2[key].id=== labels1[key].id) {
            labels1[key].simple_value= labels2[key].simple_value;
         }
     });      
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(labels1)` will return an array of items indexes, not id because `labels1` and `labels2` are arrays. you have to loop throw all item of one of the array and try to find a match item in the second one

```js
const LABELS1 = [
{"id":"bread", "simple_value":"Bread"},
{"id":"apple", "simple_value":"Apple"}
];
    const LABELS2 = [
{"id":"bread", "simple_value":"Bread with Butter", "detailed_value":"Toasted Bread with a Dab of Butter"},
{"id":"wine", "simple_value":"Wine", "detailed_value":"Wine with Cheese"}
];
    var labels1= LABELS1;
    var labels2= LABELS2;
        
      for(const label1 of labels1) {
        const label2Index = labels2.findIndex(label2 => label2.id === label1.id)
        if(label2Index != -1) {
          label1.simple_value = labels2[label2Index].simple_value
        }

      }
     console.log(labels1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Made my day.

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the labels (#2) to their indices and later retrieve the label (#2) by its index while mapping the labels (#1) to their `simple_value`.

```js
const
  LABELS_1 = [
    { "id": "bread", "simple_value": "Bread" },
    { "id": "apple", "simple_value": "Apple" }
  ],
  LABELS_2 = [
    { "id": "bread", "simple_value": "Bread with Butter",
      "detailed_value":"Toasted Bread with a Dab of Butter" },
    { "id" :"wine", "simple_value": "Wine",
      "detailed_value": "Wine with Cheese" }
  ];

// Cache the labels (#2) to their index
const idToIndex = LABELS_2.reduce((acc, { id }, index) =>
  ({ ...acc, [id]: index }), {});

const labels = LABELS_1.map(({ id, simple_value }) => ({
  id, simple_value: ((index) =>
    LABELS_2[index]?.simple_value || simple_value)
  (idToIndex[id]) 
}));

console.log(labels);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: That's a different way to do it! Thank you.